# PHP: Displaying blog pages in unique page

Tags: php, mysql, database, unique, blogs

Can anyone tell me why im getting this error with my code:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\wamp\www\blogsite\display.php on line 30

Line 30 is the very last {

It all seem right but im missing something i guess

```
<<?php

if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_int($_GET['id'])) {
    $blogId = (int)$_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT blog_id, title, date, body FROM content WHERE blog_id='$blogId'";
    // run query and get record data and output it

} else {
    //code to return all records as list
    $dbinfo = "SELECT blog_id, title, date, body FROM content ORDER BY blog_id DESC LIMIT 0, 3";
    $result = mysql_query($dbinfo) or die(mysql_error());
    $return = '<p><a href="index.php"> Go Back To Content Page</a></p>';


   if(mysql_num_rows($result) !=0):
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo '<div id="roundedbox"><h2><a href="index.php?id=' . $row['blog_id'].$row['title'] . ' </a></h2>';
   echo '<div id="date"><h5><p>' . $row['date'] . '</p></h5></div>';
   echo substr('<p>' . $row['body'] . '</p>',0, 90)." .... "." read more</div>";

       }
       else:
         echo '<p> UH OOH! THERE IS NO SUCH PAGE IT DOES\'T EXIST </p>'; 
         echo $return;
      }
?>
```

Comment: I have give you one point to your question in order to don't go down on your profile, however you must take care on your code writing, cause it is to disorder, probably using python for a small time ( 1 day ) you could write more orderer code and not having this kind of issues

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

Just copy and paste and it should run...

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_int($_GET['id'])) {
$blogId = (int)$_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT blog_id, title, date, body FROM content WHERE blog_id='$blogId'";
// run query and get record data and output it

 } else {
//code to return all records as list
$dbinfo = "SELECT blog_id, title, date, body FROM content ORDER BY blog_id DESC LIMIT 0, 3";
$result = mysql_query($dbinfo) or die(mysql_error());
$return = '<p><a href="index.php"> Go Back To Content Page</a></p>';


 if(mysql_num_rows($result) !=0){
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 echo '<div id="roundedbox"><h2><a href="index.php?id=' . $row['blog_id'].$row['title'] . ' </a></h2>';
 echo '<div id="date"><h5><p>' . $row['date'] . '</p></h5></div>';
 echo substr('<p>' . $row['body'] . '</p>',0, 90)." .... "." read more</div>";

   }} else{
     echo '<p> UH OOH! THERE IS NO SUCH PAGE IT DOES\'T EXIST </p>'; 
     echo $return;}
  }}

  ;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a curly brace rather than a colon here.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) !=0):
```

You also need to close the curly brace on the first else before the next if statement from above.

The last else should also be using a curly brace rather than a colon.

```
else {
     echo '<p> UH OOH! THERE IS NO SUCH PAGE IT DOES\'T EXIST </p>'; 
     echo $return;
  }
```

Comment: that gave an error of arse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ':'

Comment: I revised my answer. After I submitted it I noticed you have been leaving off a bunch of curly braces.

Comment: Use KyleK's answer if you cannot be bothered to read.